# How to fetch an already opened cmd window and run commands in it from a batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

There is a bat file in which a command (`nqcmd`) is executed. This command only executes, when we open the batch file as an administrator. Otherwise, an error comes.

I tried to run the batch file as administrator from powershell, like this,

```
powershell.exe -Command "start-process -filepath C:\foo.cmd -verb runas"
```

It opens two cmd windows - a normal cmd window, in which the batch file executes and an error comes:

'nqcmd is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file',

and an administrator's cmd window.
But, in this window, that batch file does not executes. We have to type the batch file's name again and then it executes.

I wanted to ask that, in a separate batch file, can we take that instance of administrator's cmd window and then run commands in it, without manually typing in that window?

Thank you.

Comment: `Start-Process 'cmd.exe' -ArgumentList '/c', 'C:\foo.cmd' -Verb runas`

Comment: Hi @AnsgarWiechers. I tried it. It opened two cmd windows.

The first one was normal cmd window and the batch file executed in it. Then, the error, which I wrote in my question, came, and, then, the same window switched to administrator's window.

And, the second window was also of administrator's.

Comment: Show the content of `foo.cmd`.

Comment: I cannot imagine it is possible to execute commands in an administrator's `cmd` instance programmatically from a normal user's account as it appears to be a security vulnerability...

Comment: Sorry, I can't show you exact file. But, it's code is similar to,


`set env_variable_1

set env_variable_2


nqcmd -d <value1> -u <value2> -p <value3> -s <file name>`

Comment: Hi @aschipfl! Can we do it from administrator's window?

Comment: [runas docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb490994.aspx). `'nqcmd is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file',` isn't that implying foo.cmd is making a call to something that does not exist? Have you tried specifying the whole path to nqcmd in foo.cmd?

Comment: I think @blaze_125 is on the right track.  Instead of a relative path, provide the full path to nqcmd.